# Clear entity table data while application startup in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am trying to create an entity object in **spring boot**, such that entity related table data need to be cleared when application startup.

As an example if we consider a session related data need to cleared to be when application startup,
because all the old data is useless.

**Do I have to clear the table manually or is there a way to configure it?**

Comment: I believe spring database initilization can handle this for you. You can use `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` with `create-drop` value,

Comment: thanks @Sajjad, will it work only for selected table

Comment: Your question wasn't clear that you only want a specific table to be cleared at application startup. In that case, you can take a look at [CommandLineRunner](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/CommandLineRunner.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CommandLineRunner and place the code to clear your table their, CommandLineRunners always run when the application has started

```
@Component
public class TableClearer implements CommandLineRunner{
//Autowire your dependency here eg the entity repository
@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
   //place your code here
    
}

}
```